# What does it mean to say "f*** this n***a" here, and when to use it

Tags: american-english, slang, offensive-language

I was reading some jokes on Facebook ​when I saw this.
What does it mean and when will you use it?

[image]

Comment: "When to use it"?  Never.

Comment: This is a fair question, and I believe that we should be able to ask about offensive language on this site, but I cannot post an answer to that in the comments section.  But please, don't try to use this phrase.

Comment: So you're saying you don't know the meaning of *fuck* in: "Fuck this job, I'm not staying one minute longer" ? If you can understand that sentence, then understanding the "joke" (what joke? where? is it funny?) is relatively easy.

Comment: I think this has been alluded to in the existing answers, but I want to make it 100% clear: do not use the term "nigga" / "nigger". It can be used in a non-offensive way by communities which self-identify, but since you're asking this question, you're not from one of those communities. The term (commonly referred to as "the n-word") is far more offensive than "regular" swear words. Saying "fuck" may be offensive to some and shouldn't be used in a formal context, but it wouldn't raise many eyebrows these days. The n-word is a different matter entirely.

Comment: “it wouldn't raise many eyebrows these days” This actually varies quite a bit if we are talking about UK, USA or other countries.

Comment: Apparently this is a meme that arose from a misdirected text in 2015: http://www.nzherald.co.nz/lifestyle/news/article.cfm?c_id=6&objectid=11507189 And it was from a dad about some undisclosed person "D" not wanting a girl's room to be blue.

Comment: @ColleenV looks like there's no reason for that article to say it's the dad, they just assume it for some reason (messages don't give any hint and it was posted from the receiver's phone). Could be mother, father, distant relative, butler, who knows?

Comment: @Dave I've seen the same claim in multiple articles that it was the father. Presumably the stranger was the one who posted excerpts on Imgur and was the one who said it was the dad. Overall this is a good argument for not extrapolating too much from an extremely limited context. There's no clue at all to genders other than the child's in the question. The lack of context may be why the score isn't higher.

Answer (score 8):

The following represents usage in AmE. I imagine there are similarities in other English speaking regions.

---

> [nigga](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nigga)
>   Usage alert 
>   Nigga is used mainly among African Americans, but also among other minorities and ethnicities, in a neutral or familiar way and as a friendly term of address. It is also common in rap music. However, nigga is taken to be extremely offensive when used by outsiders. Many people consider this word to be equally as offensive as nigger. The words nigger and nigga are pronounced alike in certain dialects, and so it has been claimed that they are one and the same word.
>
> ---
>
> noun, *Slang: Usually Disparaging and Offensive.*
>   1. a term used to refer to or address a black person.
>   Origin of nigga
>   alteration of [nigger](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nigger), based on pronunciation
>
> [fuck you](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fuck-you)
>   interjection
>   An exclamation of very strong defiance and contempt : *Fuck you, friend, if that's your attitude (1940s+)*
>   (Dictionary.com)

*This nigga* refers to D. D is someone's nickname. Overall, *fuck this nigga* is an expression of defiance and contempt, much like *fuck you* or *fuck him*. In this exact context, it would be equivalent to *fuck him* in terms of meaning (assuming D is a male).

In this instance, *fuck this nigga* is used  instead of *fuck him* likely because of stylistic and cultural reasons. People who use *nigga* openly like this frequently use *nigga* instead of the usual pronouns in informal, casual speech.  To their friends and people in their "circle", it's often meant as a friendly term. To people with whom they are not on friendly terms, it's again a term of contempt.

I would not recommend an English language learner to use these terms ever.

Answer (score 8):

Max has covered most of the answer well, so I will just offer an alternative interpretation of the final sentence.

As this is essentially speech, not prose, you can't assume proper use of grammar. An alternative reading of the final sentence is therefore "Fuck this, nigga.", where "this" refers to the instructions from "D", not "D" the person, and "nigga" is the person they are talking to. In this interpretation, it implies that the person saying this is going to paint the room blue despite D's advice.

In the interpretation proposed by Max, the sentence splits up in to "Fuck" and "this nigga". This is just an exclamation of contempt for "D" and doesn't necessarily imply any action from the speaker.

Further context may help you decide which meaning is more relevant. I would argue that the exact meaning as posted is ambiguous, but essentially amounts to the same thing: the speaker is saying that they are unhappy with being told they can't paint the room blue because Tamiya is a girl.

I would like to echo others by strongly advising that you don't use the word "nigga" as it is very likely to cause extreme offence to others. I would recommend never using swear words in general in any polite context, regardless of what other people are doing, and to only use them around others in an informal setting if they start using them first.

Answer (score 3):

That text is written in African-American Vernacular English ([AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English)). This is a dialect common all over the USA among African-Americans, particularly in areas where they are the majority (such as certain areas of most large cities, and in some [rural inland areas in The South](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Belt_(U.S._region))). Its famous internationally as the dialect the Blues, American Rap, and most Rock & Roll music is written in.

In that dialect, "nigga" is a term of (sometimes affectionate) annoyance a black person may use to refer to another black person, usually if they are seen to be either currently or perpetually behaving badly. The racial aspect is a very important point, as **a white person using this same word to refer to a black person means something completely different (and quite offensive).**<sup>*</sup>

"D" is possibly the person's first initial, but more likely slang shorthand for male genetalia, indicating this person is a female talking about a male she is in an intimate relationship with (and likely not married to).

Another aspect of AAVE is that cursing is usually sexual in nature (rather than religiously profane like it often is in wider English). So the last sentence is further emphasis of displeasure, and expressing an intent to ignore the guy's opinion.

I'd translate it into more stock English as:

> My sexist boyfriend is insisting my daughter's room must not be painted blue, as he feels that is the incorrect color for her gender. I don't care what that jerk thinks.

<sup>* - Often some white people think they can use it in the more innocent sense. They are wrong. Context always matters.</sup>

Comment: Just an aside, my husband (who is Caucasian) got called nigga in a friendly way by Snoop Dogg, so it has been co-opted to mean "that guy" not just "that black guy".

Comment: @ColleenV - Wow! I didn't get into that particular racial combination, but its a high compliment. Occasionally white people use it for other white people too. There are all kinds of things that can mean (which is another reason I wouldn't do that. Why be confusing?)

Comment: I've removed a couple of comments. Comments should be used to clarify the answer, not for discussion. Please try to focus on the language question, even though it can be difficult for a  topic this sensitive.

Comment: I think maybe Snoop is just a friendly guy. My husband barely interacted with him, so it was just a casual comment "Hey guys, don't make that nigga wait in the car."

Comment: @ColleenV - There probably is a useful place for going into the nuanced details of proper usage of the "n-word" in various contexts, and *why* the context matters the way it does, but that place would likely be in its own question on ELU or History, not in this site, this question, or these comments.

Comment: I think a more accurate translation would be "My partner's telling me I can't paint Tamiya's room blue because she's a girl. It's ridiculous!" — in the original there's no indication that the speaker thinks badly of "D" in general, just that they think this point of view is wrong, so interpreting it as "sexist jerk" would be inappropriate. Also while I'm not familiar with the slang "D" you mention (I assumed an initial), I imagine it could mean boyfriend *or* husband (so the more general "partner" fits better).

Comment: @Dave - The context I usually see [D used in](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=The%20D) ... if someone is referring to a guy personally that way, that's very dismissive. They are implying that's basically the only use they have for him. I'm not expert enough to know if a husband is often referred to that way, but I'd be surprised (unless the guy is unemployed, or a guy of similar means would be easily acquired). "Partner" is still pretty good. I nearly used something similar. The problem is it loses the sense of male gender, which I think is very important for understanding this.

Comment: @Dave (and TED) I found an article that says the person sending the message was the girl's father, which might change how we perceive the text: http://www.nzherald.co.nz/lifestyle/news/article.cfm?c_id=6&objectid=11507189

Comment: @ColleenV - It does. I haven't heard that sense of "D" used non-sexually, so in that case I'd guess (could be wrong again) it is in fact a guy talking about an acquaintance who's initial is 'D' (of gender indeterminate, although its not common for a male to use the n-word to describe a female). It doesn't change much else though.