# Relative order of social acceptance of alternate forms of the 'N' word

Tags: colloquial-language, offensive-language

The word 'nigga' has been around for sometime now in our daily lingo, and from what I understand, it's okay for people of the African American community to use it within, but it's extremely offensive for an outsider to say so ([as outlined here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124438/what-does-it-mean-to-say-f-this-na-here-and-when-to-use-it/124441#124441)).

Recently, I have come across a new colloquialism called 'nibba', which is apparently a better version of it's 'g' counterpart, and can be used by an outsider as well.

- How did this new form originate, and is it really true that it's more acceptable?
- Is 'nigga' still that offensive, or has it become much more easier to employ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still extremely offensive.

It seems that "nibba" is a recent invention, to get around censoring software on various internet forums. However it is still referring to another person as being inferior due to the colour of their skin, and so is offensive in most contexts.

1. In most cases, you don't need to refer to the colour of a person's skin.
2. Using any noun is likely to cause offence.
3. Using any word that is in any way related to "negro" is certainly going to be offensive.
4. Using adjectives: "a white person", is less likely to be offensive. But see (1) and think if you actually need to add a racial adjective.
5. If you need to ask the question, then you don't yet know English well enough to be able to use a word in context without causing offence.

Comment: Yes, but not by members of the African-American community. Black men in the states sometimes use "nigger" and I even heard a bourgeois African-American woman preface sarcastic comments to her partner with the word "Negro" in a recent TV show. But I agree with your advice.

Comment: See my last point.  If you are a member of a community that that can use these words in a "reclaiming" sense you already know that. If you need to ask, you should never use any of these "N" words.

Comment: Yes, I agree but it merits explaining it a bit more. One thing is a white person using it, another is an African-American or Afro-Brit, etc. using it.